# Error while transaction submission in the private network

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk, private-network

So I am trying to do a transaction in the private network, I have named it standalone, I am using SSL. I started the network using docker, then created a keypair, then in another terminal ran node to use javascript, below is my code:

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');

var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://localhost:8000/tx?blob=Base64');

var kp = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromRawEd25519Seed(StellarSdk.hash("Standalone Network ; February 2017"))

var sourcePublicKey = kp.publicKey();

var receiverPublicKey = "GAI5VFPPZHJXE2O2MNMKAUBBUOMJOT6LUQYO2Q3NJXNAOGHXOYUVZMVW"

StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();

server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
.then(function(account) {
   var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: receiverPublicKey,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: '350.1234567',
  }))
  .build();
  transaction.sign(kp);
  console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));
  server.submitTransaction(transaction)
   .then(function(transactionResult) 
     {console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
      console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
      console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);})
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('An error has occured:');
      console.log(err);
    });
   })
 .catch(function(e) 
 {console.error(e);
});
```

After running the above lines of code, I get a result:

```
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }

Error: Error: write EPROTO 139644081280832:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:

    at _handleNetworkError (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/stellar-sdk/lib/call_builder.js:273:31)
    at <anonymous>
```

P.S.: I have modified the Network.js file inside the node_modules folder and added a new passphrase for the standalone network and then modified the useTestNetwork Function to use the standalone network passphrase, not the testnetwork passphrase. Please let me know, what changes do I have to make in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://localhost:8000/tx?blob=Base64');` is wrong, and should point at the server, not a specific endpoint.

Comment: I tried https://localhost:8000, still got the below response:
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> Error: Error: write EPROTO 140423567779648:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:

    at _handleNetworkError (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/stellar-sdk/lib/call_builder.js:273:31)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: The error was because of SSL certificate, I used var server = new StellarSdk.Server('http://127.0.0.1:8000', {allowHttp: true}); and that error got resolved.

Comment: "{allowHttp: true}" helps, which let u try the functionality with HTTP. Try HTTPS later after things work.